# Stop TWebBrowser script error popups, but do not stop OnShowScriptError event

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

Script error modal windows could be suppressed in TWebBrowser by setting

```
Silent := True;
```

but it prohibits also `OnShowScriptError` event.

I would like to collect script errors with `OnShowScriptError`, but stop error modal windows.

Comment: Maybe just set the `AHandled` parameter to `True` to indicate you handled this error?

Comment: @nil -- this is not enough. regular message box `alert` still could appear in this case

Comment: @Zam: No problem. They should appear, but not the diagnostics messages.

Comment: @nil: Your comment is the solution I want to! You could post it as an answer here and get your points.

Comment: are the errors actual errors or due to the fact that you run the Twebbrowser not in IE9+ mode (FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION )?

Comment: @whosrdaddy: I would like to eliminate modal windows with errors on systems where is no IE9+ installed. In this case I want to display errors in TMemo.

Comment: Ok, I see, then Zam's solution seems the be solution you are looking for?

Comment: @Zam I don't understand why my comment should be wrong, I mean your answer is basically exactly what I suggested?

Comment: @nil -- i assume the right solution is http://web.archive.org/web/20150329085438/http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/261003 (How to handle script errors as a WebBrowser control host)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Your comment is the solution I want to! You could post it as an answer
>   here and get your points.

No, you need different behavior. In sample below:
1) Message box from web browser window will appear
2) Information about error will be added to `TMemo` component

URL for testing: http://1click.sdk.1click.lv/test.asp

Javascript code on this page:

> ```
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>   alert("test1"); 
>   var t = 100 / x0;
>   </script>
> ```

Resume: user will see alert ("test"), but not information about error.

What else is important? You should enable script debugging in Internet Explorer, otherwise all information about will be missed.

[image]

Delphi sample:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://1click.sdk.1click.lv/test.asp');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Silent := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1ShowScriptError(ASender: TObject;
  const [Ref] AErrorLine, AErrorCharacter, AErrorMessage, AErrorCode,
  AErrorUrl: OleVariant; var AOut: OleVariant; var AHandled: Boolean);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(AErrorMessage);

  AHandled := True;
end;
```

[image]

What you really want is: 
http://web.archive.org/web/20150329085438/http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/261003 (How to handle script errors as a WebBrowser control host)